# lambda calculus - if more parameters needed

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, sicp

Lambda Calculus Question:

```
TRUE = lambda x y . x
FALSE = lambda x y . y
1 = lambda s z . s z
2 = lambda s z . s (s z) ...

BoolAnd = lambda x y . x y FALSE
BoolOr = lambda x y. x TRUE y
BoolNot = lambda x . x FALSE TRUE 

If I want to know the result of BoolNot 1:
BoolNot 1
(lambda x . x FALSE TRUE)(lambda s z . s (s z))
(lambda s z . s z) FALSE TRUE
(lambda x y . y) (lambda x y . x)
```

Here needs x and y 2 parameters, but only have 1 here,
How can I continue this calculus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`λ x y. E` is "shorthand" for `λx. (λy. E)`.

Thus,

```
(λ x y. y) (λ x y. x)

==> (λx. (λy. y)) (λ x y. x)

==> λy. y
```

That is, the identity function.

Comment: Thanks, but could you tell me what does λy. y mean?

Comment: @Andy I'm not sure what you're asking, but `λ` is the lowercase greek character "lambda", if that's what you're wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Think that you apply one argument at the time and at each step you have a function taking one less. It doesn't make sense to do `(not 1)` but the result is the identity function since `true` becomes the variable not used and thus it will take another argument `y` and evaluate to `y`